# Get location details from FusedLocationClient and send to server using Volley

Tags: android

How can I send the latitude and longitude provided by FusedClient to `getParams` method in Volley, if both are out of scope of each other?

This is how I get location from FusedClient:

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);  
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

@Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }
};
```

This is how I send `POST` parameters to a remote server using Volley:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Response: " + response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"That didn't work!");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map getParams() {
            Map params = new HashMap();
            //How to put latitude and longitude in this map?

            return params;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Make/Instantiate the HashMap as static/class member, which is accessible in `getParams` and `onLocationResult`.
2. Declare an int as `static/class` member in the same class as HashMap.
3. Fill the map within `onLocationResult` as

   ```
   myStaticHashMap.put("lat_" + myStaticInteger, location.getLatitude());
   myStaticHashMap.put("lang_" + myStaticInteger, location.getLongitude());
   ++myStaticInteger;
   ```
4. In the function `getParams`, return the `myStaticHashMap`.
5. Not sure about how or if you are using threading in your program. If so, you'll need to `synchronise` the access to the static member vars.

Comment: It doesn't work, can you maybe show a concrete example? I tried what you said but I get the VolleyError. Also, why do I need the static integer? Why can't I just call it latitude and longitude? the `location.getLatitude()` are out of scope .